# positioning controls on a windows form according to the form size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I have a form on which i want to place certain controls. I want them to be positioned on the form according to the form size, that is, far apart when the form is maximised and close when it is smaller in size.

How to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two properties on every windows form control **Dock** and  **Anchor** Using these you could beautifully place controls and test for different sizes of forms. Check these links and do look out for behaviour by playing around with these properties.

[Anchor & Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171633.aspx)

[Dock Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w8z0xh4(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: The way I read the original question, (s)he doesn't want to change the *size* of the controls, but only their relative positions when the container form is resized. In that case, the `Anchor` property is a better bet. See [this how-to article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte.aspx) for more information.